# Adapt layout to changing width of imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a layout where one elements changes its size dynamically (the red `imageView`). The problem is that the Views below either disapear or don't align centered.

The first two images show how it should look like:

**with `LinearLayout` below set to `match_parent`:**
[image: big imageView, match_parent]

**with `LinearLayout` below set to `wrap_content`:**
[image: small imageView, wrap_content]

**This is how it looks like if the `LinearLayout` `layout:width` attribute is wrong:**
[image: big imageView, wrap_content]

[image: small imageView, match_parent]

here is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#ffff0000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:background="#ff0000ff" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:background="#ff00ff00" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How is it possible to adapt the layout, so the green and blue elements are always centered and the space expands when the red `imageView` is big, but not cut off when it is too small?

I would prefer a xml solution, since this is just a simple example and doing this programmatically could get complicated otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer missed the "and the space expands when the red imageView is big" requirement.

You can do this using the GridLayout - layout_columnWeight is only available in, 21? or something. So you will probably want to use the v7.gridlayout support library, but it will look something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="#ff0000ff" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="#ff00ff0a" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1" />

</GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thank you, its working with `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can play With LinearLayout and weight, like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#ff0000ff" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#ff00ff00" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```